# How does google find newly emerging websites?

Tags: domain, website, search-engines, whois

Is there a place to download a list of newly emerging websites every day like search engines do? When I set up a new website, I do not create any backlink for it. How does google know my website and crawl it? Does it use some kind of whois database? But I do not think there is a whois database that allows you to query every day.

Comment: This would be the purpose of DNS.  How Google functions would not be known to anyone outside of Google.  Furthermore, questions about how Google Search works (which is a web application) is out of scope here at Super User.  **Commentary isn’t required to issue a downvote**

Comment: If you disagree with my assertion then you can bring up the topic at meta.superuser but I won’t spend time justifying my close vote in the comment section

Comment: [Google Search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search) tag description is clear in this regard though

Comment: Your question isn’t close at this time.  Others might disagree with my assertion.  However, making personal attacks, because you disagree with a downvote isn’t acceptable behavior.  I won’t be returning to this question in effort to deescalate the current conversation. Most of your questions have been upvoted so your complaint doesn’t make sense

Comment: One of the ways I think Google finds sites is by crawling existing sites, and following hyperlinks in those already indexed sites. You can also just use the Google Webmaster portal and submit your site there to get it indexed. Mentioning the link on social media will make it likely to be found by Google, so basically you can either do it manually or Google will probably index it by itself if it can find it on other sites.

Comment: You submitted this question on the wrong community.  Read the Google Search tag description.  If you are question banned on Severfault then there is a reason that is likely justified.  You would have to submit a question to meta.serverfault to better understand the reason.  (You likely have too many deleted questions)

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic states that websites and Web services are off topic here as well as "corporate support and networks" . A different set of off topic items essentially stating "except insofar as the problem is between your computer and the device". This question has nothing to do with *your* hardware or software.

Answer (score 2):

There is no authorative place to download a list of new websites, and contrary to some comments new sites are not discovered because of DNS.

Sites are typically found via a link to them or a request to the search engine. Many systems automatically "ping" Google when the site is installed or content is added to ask for an update.

Comment: I was thinking it would not be that much data to watch for changes to various major DNS providers.  I mean at the end of the day we would just be guessing how Google’s secret sauce works :$

Comment: @Ramhound Other then requests to 8.8.8.8 and maybe DoH I don't see how Google could ethically achieve this through DNS.